# Safari freezes on diagonal swipe on scrollable div content

Tags: jquery, html, css, safari, mobile-safari

I have a simple scrollable div on my Html page for MOBILE e.g.

```
       <div id="outer">
        <div id="inner">scrollable long content....</div>
        </div>

        and CSS
        #outer {
            background: white none repeat scroll 0 0;
            height: 300px;
            left: 0;
            margin-top: 47px;
            padding: 0.5rem;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            width:65%;
            z-index: 1200;

        }
        #inner{
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0px;
           overflow: auto;
            -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; 
        }
```

Issue is that If I scroll diagonally say from top left to down right on my mobile screen , 
 Safari freezes for few seconds and if I keep swiping diagonally repeatedly .. Screen freezes for long time.Previously I used jQuery mobile but removed it and issue still persists in simple Html also.
            Please help.
            In fact I need scrollable side panel without scrolling main page.

Answer (score 0):

If you want only the sidebar is scrolling when visible, you must set

```
overflow = 'hidden';
```

To the content div and remove it again when closing the sidebar.
Why it freeze on mobile, is still a question.

Comment: I found -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;  was creating issue , when I removed this, diagonal swipe didn't freeze the safari. But now on rapid vertical scroll(fast up & down) ,Safari is freezing for few times.Also smoothness of scroll is not there.

Comment: Is there a solution for this problem? I've run into the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I also had a similar issue and was finally able to find out why!

In Safari, the scroll to the top was set to a negative number, and Chrome browser automatically handles it on its own.

Setting this to 0 made my scroll issue disappear.